# ethernet connected but no internet Debian 11

Tags: debian, dns, internet

ok so I connected ethernet cable it shows connected but not working ping Google not working but ping 8.8.8.8 is working how can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: put the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` in your question. BTW: it is not something simple as `ping google` not working, but `ping google.com` is working is it?

Answer (score 0):

So many unknowns in this question. Try to get more information Like do you have the firewall turned on ? is it blocking port 53? try to see if you have a default route to it with traceroute which uses a udp packet and a unprivileged port

traceroute -4 -n 8.8.8.8

Should tell you something then to see if you have a tcp route to it which requires root privilege with

sudo traceroute -4 -n -T -p 53 8.8.8.8

One or both of these should tell you if your being blocked.

What is it that's failing ? if both the traceroutes work did you try nslookup with a third argument ?

nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8

if that works then you have to look at /etc/resolv.conf to see what your default nameserver is set to, sounds like it should have a line something like

nameserver 8.8.8.8

refer to man resolv.conf if it's not